# How can i retrieve the datas in one column from a list?

Tags: document-library, rest, sharepoint-rest-api, api

I have a big document library. And i am using C sharp.
When the user selects one document from the frontend website(like click method), I want to be able to get the value in `Column A` of the selected document.
I am not interested in datas in other columns.
Thanks.

[image]

Comment: you just want to get that value when customer clicks to select item or upon editing the metadata?

Comment: When customer clicks to item. Maybe i can do this with ajax. I Don't know which way is the best for me. But now i am trying to pull data from backend.